# issue with custom delegate and datasource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, datasource

I have a custom delegate and datasource. But I have several problems with it when I try to initialize it.  In my .h file if have it like this.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<KalDataSource> dataSource;
```

This has as an result that in the synthesize in the .m file I get the following error.

```
Existing ivar 'dataSource' for property 'dataSource' with assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained.
```

After some google search magic I found that I should assing my variables like this.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<KalDataSource> dataSource;
```

But then I get this error.

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates are usually `weak` references.

The object using the delegate doesn't own it.
It's just a reference to an object which could, or could not be responding.
Weak says, that if the real owner of the object releases it, it should be deallocated.
The weak reference is then automatically set to `nil` and you don't get any zombies.

Second, the problem is, that you already have property called `dataSource`.

---

## EDIT

My previous statement about the duplicate property turns out to be wrong.
You should override the setters & getters, both the declaration in the `.h` and the implementation in the `.m` file.

Comment: duplicate symbol _KalDataSourceChangedNotification in:
    /Users/geelenstef/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Offitel-cpxhgfgbmhddbwbpmyjydsswuygz/Build/Intermediates/Offitel.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Offitel.build/Objects-normal/i386/AgendaViewController.o
    /Users/geelenstef/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Offitel-cpxhgfgbmhddbwbpmyjydsswuygz/Build/Intermediates/Offitel.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Offitel.build/Objects-normal/i386/KalViewController.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @StefGeelen If you comment out the property, do you still get the error message? Could be any duplicate symbols. If not, how are `AgendaViewController` and `KalViewController` related?

Comment: I copied the code from KalViewController in my AgendaViewController. Because I need to add code to the AgendaViewController class and don't want to touch the KalViewController class

Comment: @NSAddict `@dynamic` is not meant to be a means of cheating the compiler for a setter and a getter, it's meant to indicate that the setter and getter are defined elsewhere (as with core data).

Comment: @CodaFi As far as I know, it's here to say, in any context, if the instance variable should be created or not. The setters & getters are being created. If the superclass has a property and synthesises it, it creates a variable, like `_dataSource`. `@dynamic` just tells the compiler that it shouldn't create the instance variable, because it already exists.

Comment: @StefGeelen Are you sure that you have changed all the class names, all protocol names, and so on?

Comment: I fixed it by just deleting kalViewController.h and kalViewController.m

Comment: @NSAddict `@dynamic` has nothing to do with iVars, what it has to do with are accessors, specifically ones that you have no control over (I.e. NSManagedObject subclasses).  If accessors are not defined by the superclass, this will crash.

Comment: @CodaFi But if you override a property class type, it always implements the accessors. How should you do it correctly then?
For example I have an `NSViewController`, but I want to change the property of the window, to `ITWindow *window` rather than `NSWindow *window`.

Comment: you override the getter for the property.  Declaring it `@dynamic` is never the way to fix synthesis errors.

Comment: @CodaFi this doesn't change the property type. The property is still declared as a `NSWindow`, which doesn't really help at all. The point is so I can use the dot syntax.

Comment: @NSAddict You can use dot syntax on methods.  And if you override the getter with your subclassed type, you can, in fact, get it properly.  It even works with class methods (NSFileManager.defaultManager is perfectly valid).  In fact, this is even the recommended style in [Github's ObjC coding conventions](https://github.com/github/objective-c-conventions).

Comment: @CodaFi I just tried it, it doesn't work. The return type changes to `id`. I have overridden the `setter` & `getter` method, both with the subclass of `NSWindow`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21433/discussion-between-codafi-and-nsaddict)

Answer (score 1):

The error you're experiencing has nothing to do with your memory qualifiers (they were right the first time around). The problem lies in the fact that you have declared a backing iVar somewhere without qualifiers.  When iVars are declared, they are implicitly strong, so if you go to your shadowing iVars, and prepend `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained`, the warning should disappear.  Of course a better solution would be to just remove your backing iVars altogether, because Xcode will synthesize them for you.

Comment: @codiFi I fixed it by deleting KalViewController.h and .m but can you explain your answer a little bit so that I understand the problem.

Comment: @StefGeelen I have explained it as best I could.  What specifically is troubling you?

Comment: Ok I think that you mean backing iVars are variables assigned as 'id' And that if you have two times the same variables declared of type id, Xcode begins to complain ? Is this correct ?

Comment: @StefGeelen Not quite.  What it's really like is if I've got a strong property, but an Assign backing iVar, the compiler raises a stink about them being incompatible.